# angularjs routing under category

Tags: angularjs

I am designing an application, in which I have around 20+ categories of products and each category has it's own controllers and templates to display them, but to get more user friendly we have generic identification number, using that I need to check the category and proceed with that particular controller, I am not sure how to map with my existing controllers, using "resolve" will be too much kill since I got for each category 5+ actions, any help appreciated.

Example code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/electronics',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/electronics.html',
            controller: 'ElectronicsController'
        }).
        when('/textiles',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/textiles.html',
            controller: 'TextilesController'
        }).
        when('/furnitures',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/furnitures.html',
            controller: 'FurnituresController'
        }).
        when('/productId/productId',{
        })
}
])
```

the last routing /productId/productId should be able to send the product id to server and get product type and redirect to specific controller listed above, please advice.

Comment: need more details like router you are using. Is fairly easy to access url params depending on which router. Show what you are trying in your resolves. It is always best to post your code even knowing it isn't working as expected. That way people can see where you are getting hung up and it is the basis of how SO works

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, thanks for your reply, I have added the code above.

Comment: Put parameters in urls and use those `$routeParams` to filter data. Suggest you upgrade and use UI Router for even more flexibility